# Is there a way to apply dense rank on max expression in JPA criteria API?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, criteria

I want to write this query in java using JPA criteria API :

```
select case when 
max(field) keep (dense_rank first order by datfin desc nulls first) is null then 1 
else 0 end as flag
```

from MYTABLE;

I've an alternate query that I wrote in criteria that could do the same, but i'm wondering if there are way to emulate `max(field) keep (dense_rank first order by datfin desc nulls first)` with the criteria API.